# Rails / Devise / ActiveAdmin: issue accessing active_admin tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, stack, activeadmin

I'm using `devise` and `active_admin` and whenever I visit localhost:3000/admin and select `Users` or `Admin Users` tab, rails crashes with a very long trace:

```
... ... ...
b77ae000-b77af000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77af000-b77ca000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 374939     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77ca000-b77cb000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 374939     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b77cb000-b77cc000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 374939     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
bfd8b000-bfda0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
Aborted
```

Here are contents for `routes.rb` and `app/admin/users.rb`.

```
# config/routes.rb
... ... ... 
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :users
...

# app/admin/users.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [i686-linux]`

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in ruby interpreter. Install 1.9.3-p327.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2436